# Using job to delete data from Elastic seach asynchronously

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to delete data from Elastic search using API (curl).
I would like to start the deletion process and later query about the progress of deletion process.
Is it possible to use job to do it?
I tried looking at relevant documentation but the amount of examples is very low.
Would appreciate any relevant information or links.

Comment: What kind of deletion do you want to make? delete an index? delete documents by query? delete documents by id?

Comment: @Val I would like to delete data from specific timestamp back. For example, all data from before 3/10/2018, 10:00. If you have any ideas that might push me in relevant direction, I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

You have two solutions:

1. Using the [delete-by-query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html) using a `range` query that you can then monitor using the [Task API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html#docs-delete-by-query-task-api)
2. Use daily indices (e.g. `my-logs-2018-09-10`, `my-logs-2018-09-11`, etc) so deleting data in the past is simply a matter of deleting the indices for the days you want to ditch. No need to monitor as this happens instantaneously